# How to use View Flipper to navigate between two activities

Tags: android

I have two activities and I want to navigate between these two activities with flipview?

Answer (score 0):

view flipper is used only for navigation between views only not for activities.

From android 2.1 onwards there is method

Intent intent = new Intent(Fisrst.this, Second.class);

startActivity(intent);
**overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right);**

so use like that. I think it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Comment: instead to say about Activity it say for Fragment...any suggestion to get same for Activity.